# what is the difference between scansets in scanf() function?

Tags: c, scanf

I have read all of the questions about these, but I have not found an explanation for the difference between `%[^\n]s` and `%[^\n]` in the `scanf()` function.

Comment: @user3121023 after it see \n character,it tries to read s?

Comment: In a nutshell: `%[^\n]` is correct, and `%[^\n]s` is a very common and very confusing mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extra `s` after `%[^\n]` is a common mistake. It may come from a confusion between scansets and the `%s` conversion specifier.

Its effect in a `scanf` format string is a match for an `s` byte in the input stream. Such a match will always fail because after the successful conversion of the `%[^\n]` specifier, the stream is either at end of file or the pending character is a newline. Unless there are further conversion specifiers in the format string, this failure will have no effect on the return value of `scanf()` so this bug is rarely an issue.

Note also these caveats:

- the `%[^\n]` specifier will fail on an empty line.
- it is safer to always specify the maximum number of bytes to convert for the `%[]` and `%s` specifiers to avoid undefined behavior on unexpectedly large inputs.
- `scanf("%99[^\n]", line)` will leave the newline pending in the input stream, you must consume it before you can read the next line with the same `scanf` format string.

Contrary to `while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) { ... }`, you cannot simply write `while (scanf("%99[^\n]", line) == 1) { ... }` to read the whole file line by line, you must consume the pending newline in the body of the loop and the loop would stop at the first empty line.

Example:

```
char line[100];
if (scanf("%99[^\n]", line) == 1) {
    /* handle input line */
} else {
    /* stream is at end of file or has an empty line */
}
```

Comment: Another caveat: consider how `while (scanf("%99[^\n]", line) == 1) {`  will get fail to read subsequent lines of input.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `[^\n`] in `scanf()` means skip over any new line char. It consumes all apart from new line char.

The the * flag signals that no assignment should be made. In this case * char. [\n] skips over any leading newline characters

In other words: `%*[^\n]` scans means  everything until a \n(Doesn't scan \n) and discards.

Comment: s in %[^\n]s what does mean?